# How to get correct Time with moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using moment.js for formatting date and time with format function, I'm getting correct output for date but whereas time is setting to 12:00 AM for all times by default. What ever time I give for below code it sets to 12:00 AM. Is there way to fix it?

```
  console.log(moment('2020-10-22 11:00:00', 'YYY-MM-DD').format('MMM DD - h:mm A'))
  //Received output: Oct 22 - 12:00 AM
  //Expected output: Oct 22 - 11:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `moment` that it has to take into account the time other than the date.

```
console.log(moment('2020-10-22 11:30:00', 'YYY-MM-DD h:mm').format('MMM DD - h:mm A'))
//                                                   ^^^^
// In this case output is
// Oct 22 - 11:30 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, here working example:

```js
console.log(moment('2020-10-22 11:00:00', 'YYY-MM-DD hh:mm').format('MMM DD - h:mm A'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You forgot to put hour and minute format in `moment()` call